# Make Cucumber "setup method" run only if step from that class is run

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I am making use of the `@Before` Cucumber tag to have a setup method for any step listed within that file. However, I only want this method to run if the current execution of Cucumber includes a step that is listed within that file.

Currently, all the specified `@Before` methods run, no matter if the scenario being run attempts to execute a step definition within a file.

So for example:

```
 public class StepDefA {
        @Before
        public void setupA() {
            // do setup
        }

        @Then("^some step$")
        public void thenSomeStep() { }
    }

    public class StepDefB {
        @Before
        public void setupB() {
            // more setup
        }

        @Then("^some other step$") {}
    }


Scenario:
Then some step # setupA and setupB both run
```

The problem is that despite me only executing "some step", the setupB is run. I want only setupA to run since the step being run is in that file. Is there a way of getting around this?

Answer (score 2):

You could try using *tagged hooks*, like this:

```
...

public class StepDefB {
    @Before("@tag")
    public void setupB() {
        // more setup
    }

    @Then("^some other step$") {}
}

...
```

Then, inside the `.feature` file you just tag the scenarios with `@tag`.

```
Feature: Test feature

  @tag
  Scenario: Test scenario with setupB
    ...
    Then some other step
```

Now, `setupB()` should only run for that scenario.

You could also create a method without ony hooks inside `StepDefB`, and just run that method inside the step code before anything else:

```
public void setupB() {
    // more setup
}
```

and then:

```
@Then("^some other step$") {
    setupB();
}
```

Hope you get it working.